# Why won't this C program print the unsigned int?

Tags: c, printf

I wrote this function to reverse a number. I will have test cases that are up to 2^32. I need the function to return unsigned ints. My question is this: why wont this print?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

unsigned int reverse(unsigned int a);

int main(){

    printf("%u\n",reverse(987654321));
    //printf("%ui\n",reverse(987654321)); //this wont work either

    return 0;
}

unsigned int reverse(unsigned int a)
{
    int temp=0;
    while(a>0)
    {
        temp=10*temp+a%10;
        a/=10;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Yes I did forget about the proto-type... Bear with me I have been doing Java and Lisp lately. However, my compiler keeps giving me a warning saying I have extra characters in the format string. It also does this if I have type "long long int" and I use "%lli% in the format string, which I also tried.

Comment: Do you get any compiler errors or warnings?

Comment: It works for me (compiled and tested). Suggest however that you put `main()` after `reverse()` or add a forward declaration for `reverse()`.

Comment: What results or problems do you get?

Comment: What was the result (compile or run time) of using `printf("%u\n",reverse(987654321))`.  "wont work" is not descriptive enough - post what happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to include prototype for your function before `main`.

```
unsigned int reverse(unsigned int a);
```

Comment: But `int` and `unsigned int` are layout compatible, and the implicit return type is `int`, so this should work.

Comment: @KerrekSB; Depends on whether OP is compiling it in C89 or C99 mode.

Comment: Yes, true. However, it's still valid C11 to only have a declaration, `unsigned int reverse();` before first use, rather than a full prototype.

Answer (score 0):

The number probably is just too big for an `unsigned` on your architecture.

Remember to always enable maximum warning level for your compiler. This should have told you that `reverse` is not known where you use it, that you are passing an `int` to the `%u` format and also that your number ist too big.

Comment: Note the number is not too big for even a *signed* 32 bit int.  While it is not impossible the poster is targeting a 16 bit system, most of those in existence today are embedded or emulation environments that would probably have been mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Chris: you'd be surprised how many students in e.g. Indian colleges are still using 16 bit Turbo C.